# Ansible - Recursive copy

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to copy the content of my directories (located on my bastion) on a server but it doesn't work.
I tried with "with_fileglob:", "with_items:" but each times, I had the error :

```
"'item' is undefined"
```

I don't understand why.

Ths is my code which doesn't work:

```
  tasks:
   - name: Copy directories...
      copy:
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{ dir_dest }}/"
        owner: "{{ dir_owner }}"
        group: "{{ dir_group }}"
        mode: '0755'
        with_fileglob:
          - /home/ansible/delivery/my_dir/*
```

whereas this one works :

```
  tasks:
  - name: Copy directories...
      copy:
        src: "/home/ansible/delivery/my_dir/"
        dest: "{{ dir_dest  }}/"
        owner: "{{ dir_owner }}"
        group: "{{ dir_group }}"
        mode: '0755'
```

But I can't use this 2nd solution because I have a lot a directories to copy.

Thank for your help.

Comment: In your first example, `with_fileglob` is mis-indented. The `copy` module does not have a `with_fileglob` parameter; you need to out-dent it to the same level as `name` because it's a task parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me well. Have a good end of day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tasks:
- name: Copy directories...
   copy:
     src: "{{ item }}"
     dest: "{{ dir_dest }}/"
     owner: "{{ dir_owner }}"
     group: "{{ dir_group }}"
     mode: '0755'
   with_fileglob:
    - /home/ansible/delivery/my_dir/*
```

Try this.

Comment: A space is missing under "with_fileglob:" before the dash but otherwise it's good. Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries glad to help.